# Closing socket connection on running console application

Tags: osx, tcp, socket, node.js

I am testing a chat bot and want to gracefully handle for times when the chat server isn't running so it can come back up when the service is available again. I have the programming handled. My question is how to test this when the downtimes are not reliable. Someone suggested "Terminate the socket connection manually". How would I do this?

This is a console node.js running on Mountain Lion. Can I sever a connection to a server from a single application?

Comment: How about details of the implementation?  C/Java/Python?  OS?  And maybe a clarification from the person making the suggestion as to what they meant.

Comment: The tags said it all, but I added it to the question anyway.

Answer (score 2):

For closing an in-progress connection, you can forge a TCP RST packet.  The `tcpkill` utility included in [dsniff](http://www.monkey.org/~dugsong/dsniff/) can do this.  According to the [dsniff FAQ](http://www.monkey.org/~dugsong/dsniff/faq.html#What%20platforms%20are%20supported), "a MacOS X port is available via [MacPorts](http://macports.org/)".  You could also run this from another computer on the same unfiltered Ethernet segment, or from a dedicated firewall, etc.

To prevent a connection from being created in the first place, firewall rules are your best bet, either on your local machine or again on some dedicated firewall.

For an even simpler solution: just unplug your network cable.

Comment: Well, ya unplugging works. But then I don't have a connection for other stuff.

Comment: Then use the other real solutions that I listed first.